# Source of phpinfo fields

Tags: php

Is there a way to know where is set a given PHP config property?

When I run `phpinfo()` I get a list of properties with values, example:

`max_input_time 60 120`

Here I know that the actual value of **max_input_time** is 120.

Is there a way to know where  this values was set? global php.ini? local php.ini? hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate if an option was set via ini_set, .htaccess php_value or php.ini.

Comment: I agree with the unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It's right on top of the output. Look for "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed".

Comment: I know this! but I want to know where a particular property was set

Comment: Typically it's right in the order of the displayed ini files. The last one overwrites settings from the previous ones. But I don't know of a function or method that tells were a settings was set. You have to look it up for yourself.

Comment: The only solution is to look up the ini files for yourself, starting from the last parsed one up to the first - there is no function or anything similar that is telling you where a specific ini setting was set.

Answer (score 0):

The master settings come from the PHP config file (php.ini). You can find the source of this file near the top in the section "Loaded Configuration File" (will read something like "/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini" or "c:\Program Files\php5\php.ini"  (Prior to PHP 5.2 the value is shown in "Configuration File (php.ini) Path")

The local settings come from three places; a directive in a apache config (httpd.conf or vhosts.conf etc), a directive in .htaccess, or an ini_set() that comes before the pho_info() call.

The other place to look is declared in the php_info - top table "additional .ini files parsed" - check in there too.

Comment: I know where proprties **could be set** I want to know where a particular property was set

Comment: In that case, to answer exactly where it was set, you can't find it.  It's one of the above places, and that's the best you're going to do. Sorry!